# How to customize jquery mobile build?

Tags: jquery-mobile, zepto

We would like to make jquerymobile lighter by removing modules we dont need.

Want to keep only some widgets, ui control decorations and touch event processing.

Would also like to use Zepto instead of the full jquery library...

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQM is now decoupled:

- http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2011/08/03/jquery-mobile-beta-2-released/

> **Widgets: Now decoupled for flexible builds**
>
> We’ve wanted to decouple all our widgets from the page plugin for a
>   long time now and we’re happy to announce that we finally landed this
>   change. So what exactly does decoupled mean anyway? Well, the
>   individual widgets and utilities have always been broken out into
>   separate script files. However, the page plugin was responsible for
>   handling the auto-initialization all of the official plugins found in
>   the markup at page creation. This situation made it impossible to
>   remove plugins you don’t need without causing errors, and generally
>   set a bad precedent for future widget additions.
>
> Now, pretty much all the UI widgets in the jQuery Mobile library are
>   completely decoupled so they can simply be deleted if not needed for a
>   particular project. This change allows you to dramatically reduce the
>   size of the library by only including the specific set of widgets or
>   features you need, in addition to the handful of required, core files.
>   While we still plan to do more decoupling and cleanup, the following
>   files are now decoupled and can safely be removed from the make file
>   before you do a custom build:
>
> - page header/content/footer
> - collapsible
> - controlgroup
> - fieldcontain
> - fixheaderfooter
> - button
> - checkboxradio
> - select
> - slider
> - textinput
> - links theming
> - listview
> - navbar
> - grid
>
> We will work on a dependency map because a few widgets rely on others
>   to work. For example, the button markup plugin is called by many of
>   the widgets above, so it can only be excluded but if you’re not using
>   any of the widgets that depend on buttons.
>
> We’re still working out our recommendations for mapping plugin
>   dependencies and decoupling things even further. Ultimately, this will
>   be surfaced in a download builder tool, so stay tuned!

You can head over to their GIT Repo and just download what you want:

- https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/tree/master/js

Comment: Thank you. Is there an updated list of decoupled modules? The link shows many more js files than the ones listed in the beta  release note. Also has anybody successfully used jquery mobile with Zepto?

Comment: Not at the moment but poking around the Git Repo you might find something: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/wiki/List-of-widgets-in-jQuery-Mobile https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/wiki also if you're on twitter they (The Dev's) answer questions. I know a download builder is in the works but nothing solid as of yet

Comment: Thanks I was able to reduce size by about 12k ... will see how much more I can do without.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you're just looking for event support, but this worked for me:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile.define.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile.core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile.media.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile.support.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile.vmouse.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile.event.js"></script>
```